# Limitar range para exibição do tooltip em gráfico de área com Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Estou fazendo um gráfico de area com o Highcharts e preciso que o tooltip seja exibido apenas quando eu posicionar o cursor do mouse no ponto da série, e não na linha.

Alguém sabe se há como fazer isso?

Meu exemplo: [Aqui](http://jsfiddle.net/brunomucelinibmucelini/0rpceust/)

Att

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estive á procura e não encontrei uma solução direta. Pelos vistos isto não é possivel como "opção", mas dá para fazer.

Lendo estas duas respostas no SOen <sup>[[(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17528145/2256325) [(2)]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16898591/2256325)</sup> dá para fazer isso usando séries `type: 'scatter'`. Uma vez que essa série não dá para mostrar a área, precisa de ter o que já tem  e adicionar outra linha `type: 'scatter'` com os mesmos dados. Precisa ainda de juntar uma função nas opções do tootip:

```
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        formatter: function () {
            if (this.points && this.points.length == 1) {
                return false;
            } else {
                var p = this;
                return 'x: ' + p.x + '<br/>y: ' + p.y;
            }
        }
    },
```

#### Exemplo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/0rpceust/1/)